# sudo apt-get ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros E: unable to locate package

Tags: slam, navigation, ubuntu, rasbperrypi, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 on Raspberry Pi 2. And ROS kinetic base is installed on it, every other package installs easily but I am unable to resolve the issue while installing rtabmap-ros. I have tried using ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS image for ARM and installed a Lubuntu desktop on it but the error is still present.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242666/sudo-apt-get-ros-kinetic-rtabmap-ros-e:-unable-to-locate-package/) by [Mate](https://answers.ros.org/users/27860/mate/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-08-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2016-08-29**:
Maybe the package just is not released?

**Comment by [Mate](https://answers.ros.org/users/27860/mate/) on 2016-08-29**:
I have tried on my desktop with Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS it gets installed easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Binaries for arm are not built because `libpcl-dev` was not found on the initial release of Kinetic: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/issues/80, so rtabmap build is disabled on arm (don't remember where exactly on the buildfarm it is set).We may check to re-enable if libpcl-dev is now released. For now, you may have to build rtabmap from source: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros#build-from-source

Build status: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_uxhf.html?q=rtabmap

**EDIT**: It looks like `pcl_ros` package is not built either: http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_uxhf.html?q=pcl

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4